# Why does my find command get executed two times?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, find

I want to retrieve specific files then `cp` the result into another directory.  It is all working, but my command seems to be executed a second time.

For example, I have a file `a` and I want to `cp` it into subdirectory `test/`, so I run:

```
find . -mtime -1 -name a -exec cp {} test/ ';'
```

My file is copied into the subdirectory as I wanted but then I get this error message:

```
cp: './test/a' and 'test/a' are the same file
```

Comment: seems you already have a file in test, you can limit find to current directory with `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: or exclude it from the `find -name a ! -path './test/*' ...`

Comment: there was no file in the test directory prior to the command

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a race condition - first `find` finds `./a` and copies it to `test/a`, then it finds the newly copied `./test/a` and tries to copy it again:

```
$ find . -mtime -1 -name a -print -exec cp -v {} test/ ';'
./a
'./a' -> 'test/a'
./test/a
cp: './test/a' and 'test/a' are the same file
```

You could avoid that by telling `find` not to descend into the target directory ex.

```
find . -path ./test -prune -o -mtime -1 -name a -exec cp {} test/ ';'
```

Comment: I think the term "race condition" is not correct here, because AFAIK there's no concurrency going on and this behavior is determinstic.

Comment: @WayneConrad GNU find in its `man` page does clearly define `find` to be mono-thread, however the [POSIX definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/find.html) does not mention the fact that `find` will use a single thread to check the files. So it is possible to implement `find` to spawn more threads to recursively visit the directories, in which case the behaviour described by the question would actually be a proper race condition. AFAIK neither the POSIX definition nor the GNU man page define ordering of the checks, so this answer would work for both.